# alternative definition of riemann integral question

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $g(x)$ is a Riemann integrable function. I am able to prove that if $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of Riemann sums (of $g$ on the interval $[s,t]$) whose partition is becoming finer and finer, then,
$$
\int_{s}^t g(u) du = \lim_{n\to\infty} M_n.
$$
My question is why can't we use this equivalency as the definition of the Riemann integral?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $s=0, t=1$ and the function $g$ is 1 on the rationals and zero on the irrationals.  Then you can have the Riemann sum $M_n$ be equal to zero for all $n$, or be equal to one for all $n$, depending on which points you choose to evaluate $g$ at.  So the sums both converge, but to different places.  The upper and lower sums do not converge to each other, so the function is not (and should not be) Riemann integrable.

On the other hand if we know already that $g$ is Riemann integrable then we know no matter what points we choose to evaluate $g$ at in each interval of the partition, it will always converge to the same place.

Comment: I believe what the OP has in mind is that $f$ is Riemann integrable iff any sequence of Riemann sums with vanishing mesh converges to some (unique) $A$.